# Adding two paths to d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would appreciate any help on this! I am currently attempting to add two paths from two different csv files to code adapted from this Focus+Context via Brushing d3 visualization: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.area {
  fill: none;
stroke: #000;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.area_ {
  fill: none;
stroke: #a0f2;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush_ .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]),
x_ = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2_ = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y_ = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2_ = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
xAxis2_ = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2_).orient("bottom"),
 xAxis_ = d3.svg.axis().scale(x_).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"),
yAxis_ = d3.svg.axis().scale(y_).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brushed);

var brush_ = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2_)
    .on("brush", brushed);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

var area_ = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x_(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y_(d.price); });

var area2 = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.price); });

var area2_ = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x2_(d.date); })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(function(d) { return y2_(d.price); });


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");



d3.csv("sp500.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height2 + 7);
});

d3.csv("academia_score.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  x_.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
  y_.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))]);
  x2_.domain(x_.domain());
  y2_.domain(y_.domain());

  focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area_);


  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area2_);


  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height2 + 7);
});
function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".area_").attr("d", area_);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}

function type(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.price = +d.price;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

However, the brush zoom is not working on my second path. The output can be viewed on this page: http://researchiq.net/comp.html Why isn't the zoom working on the second path??? Thanks!

Comment: Hey @user1011332 how did my answer work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

Because `d3.select()` only selects a single element, not multiple, so `focus.select(".area")` is incorrect. Switch it to `focus.selectAll(".area")` and, assuming everything else was done properly, you'll be good to go.